# Mac upgraded PHP to 5.6, but CLI php -v get 5.3.28?

Tags: php, macos, composer-php

I have installed MAMP (comes with PHP 5.5) on my machine. And localhost pointed to /Applications/MAMP/htdocs. The problem happened when I was trying to use composer in terminal to install dependencies in htdocs. Composer complained that PHP must be 5.4 or above.

I guess it complained about PHP comes with OSX. So I have upgraded PHP to 5.6 by

```
curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.6
```

But when I do

```
$ php -v
```

I still get

```
PHP 5.3.28 (cli) (built: Aug 29 2014 18:52:17) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

And Composer is still complaining...

Why is that? And how to fix this?

Comment: php 5.3 is probably earlier in your $path than 5.6. Either remove 5.3, or move 5.6 to somewhere in the path that's before 5.3

Comment: Do `which php` in terminal to see which binary is used. Do `echo $PATH` to see in which order the binary directories are searched when you type a command. The installer may have appended the php install dir in PATH variable in /Users/myusername/.profile file.

Comment: Thank you, both Marc and jkj, I am able to find a solution as below in the answer.

Comment: For what it's worth, if you upgrade to Mavericks, you'll get 5.4.24 in /usr/bin.

Comment: I am using Mavericks, but somehow installed Apache2, which makes the conflicts. So by removing Apache2, it solved the problem.

Answer (score 25):

If you have upgraded using curl, copy & paste the following line of code and press enter.

```
$ export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH
```

Now, type

```
$ php -v
```

If done correctly, it should show the following

```
PHP 5.6.23 (cli) (built: Jun 26 2016 13:17:47) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by Derick Rethans
```

Comment: After hours of searching, this is what worked for me, thank you!

Answer (score 10):

If you installed PHP 5.6 using [Homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php), this works:

Open Terminal, run `open -a TextEdit ~/.bash_profile`, then paste this in the end of the file:

```
# Use Home-brewed PHP 5.6 instead of pre-installed version (5.3)
export PATH="$(brew --prefix homebrew/php/php56)/bin:$PATH"
```

Save the file and restart Terminal.

Comment: This cut the mustard. Thanks!

Comment: export PATH="$(brew --prefix php@5.6)/bin:$PATH"

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the help.

It is due to the order in $PATH, like Marc and jkj posted in the comments above.

I can't find a way to re-order the $PATH (did some research but failed to find an easy way), but I am able to fix this by simply removing the Apahce2 previously installed following this post:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41143/how-to-revert-default-mac-apache-install-to-original

update 9/9/2014:
after some research, the following procedure would make PHP version setting system wide.

The procedure comes from this [source](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/upgrade-to-php-5-4-or-5-5-mac-osx-10-8-mountain-lion/), please look for the comments down below that page and find user Amtriorix.

I am just copy/paste his solution here:

> ```
>   The php-cli version is still the Apple version if You do not change it. Your php on apache can be different as the cli version, including used modules ! So beware.
>     As Brian Wynn did mention, of course You can modify Your PATH settings to write into your ~/.profile file the following
>     export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH
>     Most likely a better approach is to make the setting system wide.
>     You should symlink to the right php executable.
>     So:
>     #cd /usr/bin
>     #mv php php.org
>     #ln -s /usr/local/php5/bin/php
>     test if it works:
>     #php -v && php -m && php --ini
>     --> should be php-osx version with related modules...
> ```

Comment: you can set $PATH to whatever you want in your ~/.bash_profile file... you can do this: `echo "PATH='$PATH'" >>~/.bash_profile`, and then edit the file and change the PATH to what you want.  Next time you start a new Terminal, that will be your PATH.

Comment: mv: rename php to php.org: Operation not permitted

Answer (score 0):

1. Look at the terminal history to see where the new version was installed (probably /usr/local)
2. Type 'which php' into terminal to see where current version is located (this should be different that new version)
3. Go to users/username/.bash_profile
4. Replace the old location with the new location, or add another location after the original location, separated by a colon (if you replace, you may break something else, depending on location).
5. Restart terminal, run php -v to test.

   ```
   export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local:$PATH"
   ```