# laravel 5 installation php artisan parse error expecting identifier (T_STRING)

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

Why every time when I install **Laravel 5**, after typing the command

```
laravel new project-name
```

usually I get the issue

```
Crafting application...

Parse error: parse error, expecting `"identifier (T_STRING)"' or `"variable (T_VARIABLE)"' or `'{'' or `'$'' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/artisan on line 31
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error



  [RuntimeException]  
  Error Output:       



run-script [--dev] [--no-dev] [-l|--list] [script] [args1] ... [argsN]
```

Then when I'm trying to the command  `php -S localhost:8888 -t public` to open the sever and open it in the browser I always see this issue on my home page

```
Parse error: parse error, expecting `"identifier (T_STRING)"' or `"variable (T_VARIABLE)"' or `'{'' or `'$'' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/public/index.php on line 50
```

how I can fixed it?

Comment: before running laravel new, reinstall your laravel generator via composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"

Comment: After reinstall the laravel still get the same issue :(

Comment: How is your [~]php -v ?? I'm guessing it should be above 5.5 [mh](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27169336)

Comment: PHP 5.4.24 (cli) (built: Jan 19 2014 21:32:15) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies