# Different versions of PHP on the Server vs CLI

Tags: php, macos, apache, command-line-interface

I am running a Mac, and unfortunately have the different versions of PHP running in the CLI and on Apache. I have searched and can find instances of this question before but have not been able find a reason this occurs or how to resolve the issue.

When I run phpinfo(); and load it in the browser I get the following:

Version 5.6.24

Loaded config file: /etc/php.ini

Server Path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

But when I run php -v & php --ini in the command line, I get the following:

Version 5.6.0

Loaded config file: /usr/local/lib/php.ini

When I run 'whereis php' it shows /usr/bin/php and when I run 'which php' I get /usr/local/bin/php.

Can anyone explain why this has happened? And does anyone know how this can be resolved? I would like to, if possible, resolve the underlying issue rather than find a workaround. I'd also like to uninstall the version of PHP that is not being used.

Comment: Which version do you want, that from Apache or from the CLI?

Comment: Ultimately I don't really mind as long as it's consistent but as Apache is the later version I think thats the version I should use.

Comment: How did you install Apache? Homebrew, within MAMP etc?

Comment: Apache is just the version that came installed with the Mac (upgraded to Sierra recently but I have had this problem for quite some time). I manually installed PHP a while ago (./configure make make install) and I presume I installed it incorrectly so that it effected the CLI but not Apache. I think PHP 5.6.24 may be the version that comes preinstalled with macOS Sierra, which means that it is the CLI that is effectively wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your path is set to the wrong/older version. Do a `export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH`

Restart the terminal and `php -v`

Alternatively have a look at Have a look at: [Mac upgraded PHP to 5.6, but CLI php -v get 5.3.28?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25731145/mac-upgraded-php-to-5-6-but-cli-php-v-get-5-3-28) and follow @mark-reed comment on the @bing answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Adding the export PATH= feels like more a workaround than a fix. Where is it set currently that the CLI defaults to the wrong version of PHP? Can this be resolved by any other method, or can the wrong version of PHP just be uninstalled?

Comment: Search, SO and Google find a lot of things for you. You can uninstall the wrong php version but to answer your question: Where is it set currently that the CLI defaults to the wrong version of PHP? It is not set that it defaults, but it is set that it uses that exact version. And thats exactly the PATH where this is set. So to resolve the issue change the PATH how you need it.

Answer (score 3):

Same issue with my computer.

When i check php version on terminal

```
Nanhes-MacBook-Pro:~ nanhekumar$ php -v
```

PHP 7.1.16 (cli) (built: Apr  1 2018 14:10:37) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies

http://localhost/info.php

**PHP Version 7.1.25**

Solution

you can view installed php through brew list in my case it is showing php@7.1

```
Nanhes-MacBook-Pro:~ nanhekumar$ brew link php@7.1


If you need to have this software first in your PATH instead consider running:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.1/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Then run this on terminal

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.1/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Restart terminal and again check your php version both php version are same.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo brew services stop php
```

This solved the issue for me