# error upgrading php in mac

Tags: php, macos, upgrade, symfony

I am running OSX El Capitan (version 10.11.6).

I had php 5.5 installed.

Phpunit requires php5.6 and more so I tried to upgrade my php to 5.6. I couldn't do it so I gave php7 a try.

I followed these guides:
https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/upgrade-php-on-osx/
https://php-osx.liip.ch/
[Mac upgraded PHP to 5.6, but CLI php -v get 5.3.28?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25731145/mac-upgraded-php-to-5-6-but-cli-php-v-get-5-3-28)

My current output with `php -v` is :
`PHP 7.0.12 (cli) (built: Nov  1 2016 10:21:11) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.12, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.4.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans`

Funny thing, my output with a `phpinfo();` when called from somewhere inside a Symfony project, is still `PHP Version 5.5.36`

Any ideas??

Comment: export the correct path to the new (not upgraded) php 7 binary and restart the server.

Comment: i suggest you to use brew as package manager

Comment: Would be awesome if there is a one-liner for that. But I wasn't lucky trying to find any. I had a similar problem trying to update Java and a `brew update` followed by a `brew cask install java` saved the day. What about php then? @Matteo

Comment: Hi @StLia You could simply search for modules with, as example, `brew search php7`  then install as `brew install php70`  and do a lot of stuff for you (the command will display what you need to do for apache conf as simple add the library and where). An useful think is you can simply switch to a different php version installed on the system simply do `brew unlink php70` and `brew switch php55 5.5.30`

Comment: Hmmm `brew unlink` sounds like a solution... Theoretically speaking though, because unfortunately I had no time to test it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Terminal uses a different PHP than a HTTP server in browser.** You can check what PHP you're using in CLI (command line interface) by this terminal command:

```
$ which php
```

I don't know if you use any AMP stack (like MAMP). They include their own PHP, so you need to update them in order to have a different PHP version in browser.

Maybe you can use this trick to **determine what PHP versions you use in browser / CLI**: Find the php.ini path in your phpinfo() output and compare it with this terminal command:

```
$ php -i | grep php.ini
```

Comment: I had to add  `export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH` in my ~/.profile as @Xorifelse suggested. I should mention that `which php` outputs `/usr/local/php5/bin/php` which is actually the php7 and can be confusing

Answer (score 0):

It's always a good idea to use the debug URL to troubleshoot your Symfony projects; to use this, simply append:

```
app_dev.php
```

For example if your route was like `http://myhome/`, then you would use:

```
http://myhome/app_dev.php
```

Then on the bottom of your browser you will have the Symfony debug bar. In the bottom right corner, the version of Symofny is shown, an if you move your mouse over it, you will see the version of PHP; plus also a link to "View phpinfo()". You can click on it to view the full PHP information, including where the PHP file is located.

The PHP config file used (shown on the phpinfo() page) is shown by:

```
Loaded Configuration File
```

Hope that helps!